# Local coefficient System and the action of fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

A *local coefficient system* $A\hookrightarrow E \to B$ is a fiber bundle $p:E\to B$ such that

- The fiber is a discrete abelian group $A$
- The structure group $G$ is a subset of Aut$(A)$

Is the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $A$ necessarily a homomorphism?

Comment: I do not understand: Homomorphism to where? To $Aut(A)$?

Comment: I mean I do not know whether or not $\pi_1(B) \subset Aut(A)$.

Comment: Now, it makes sense and is true, except you do not have an embedding, only a homomorphism, called the monodromy of the local system (the same will work even if A is not a group). You can find a detailed discussion for instance in Steenrod's book "Topology of fiber bundles".